# What is this Data Type for Video View of Two Controllers?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, data-structures

I am considering a data structure and data type for video view of two controllers/sliders (*timeStart*, and *timeEnd*) in contrast to current standard of one controller in video view. 
I generate myself the cells which consist of matrices etc for *n=1800* corresponding to 30 minute recording. 
I have seen such data types in SageMath software and I think they should exist in Matlab too.

### Data structure

Nested structure.

[image]

where you can go from *timeStart* 1 to *timeEnd* [1,..,n], from 2 to [2,..,n], and from 3 to [3,..,n].

### View

Output is one picture.

[image]

---

What is this Data Type for Video View of Two Controllers?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking us to write a better way for you? Are you asking for a code review? Are you asking for our *opinion* on whether or not the approach is sufficient? None of these things are on topic for SO.

Comment: @excaza Now, the body is clearer. This is a data type used in some video recordings of Matlab. It should exist but I do not know its name. I simplified the body.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There does not exist such viewer options in Matlab, robust enough for dynamic situations. 
There are many sequences of bugs existing in Linux Matlab, but solved already in Mathematica. 
Use Mathematica 11 in Debian instead.